# Property observers in Lua

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua, property-observer

Is there way to add a property observer in Lua just like Swift does for WillSet and DidSet with properties?

For example, I have a object of display.newText and whenever I change it's text property. I need to do something other as well? Like
object.text = "Changed"

I know I can add a method like setText() or something but I'm looking for property observers in Lua language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proxy table. This is explained in [Pil, Chapter 13](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html).